# How is nested template specialization done C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated function defined as:

```
template<typename TObject> TObject Deserialize(long version, const Value &value)
```

what I need to do, is to write a specialization which would take vector defined as:

```
template<typename TNum, int cnt> class Vec
```

and still has access to *cnt* and *TNum*.

I have unsuccesfully tried

```
template<typename TNum, int cnt> Vec<TNum, cnt> Deserialize<Vec<TNum, cnt>>(long version, Value &value)
```

resulting in error: illegal use of explicit template arguments

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: You can't partially specialize functions. Thus you have to hide the actual implementation into a static method of a dummy template struct, and specialize that entire struct.

Comment: Only a vector or any container?

Comment: In my case Vec is the mathematic vector from external library.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I wish this advice would not be given so quickly. 9/10 times the correct answer is to overload, not forward to a struct. Functions don't have partial specialization in part because they simply don't need it.

Comment: @NirFriedman You're right, but OP's function doesn't have a single argument depending on the template parameter. IIRC, unless they want to go for tag dispatch, they have to specialize through a struct.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, but even so it's still generally better to implement with functions, you have more flexibility and it's cleaner for allowing user specialization.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat My answer uses tags but maybe it's not quite the tag dispatch you were thinking of; it still leverages the mechanisms of partial specialization as opposed to have truly different overloads taking `true_type` and `false_type` based on some trait info.

Comment: @NirFriedman This is the kind of tag dispatch I was thinking of. You're right, it looks better than struct specialization in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, the correct answer to dealing with function templates and needing to partially specialize them, is to simply overload them instead. In this case this trick doesn't work directly because there are no arguments that depend on the template parameter, i.e. the template parameter is explicitly specified and not deduced. However, you can forward along to implementation functions, and make overloading work by using a simple tag struct.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <class T>
struct tag{};

template<typename TObject> 
TObject Deserialize_impl(long version, tag<TObject>) {
    std::cerr << "generic\n";
    return {};
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
std::array<T,N> Deserialize_impl(long version, tag<std::array<T,N>>) {
    std::cerr << "special\n";
    return {};
}

template<typename TObject> 
TObject Deserialize(long version) {
    return Deserialize_impl(version, tag<TObject>{});
}


int main() {
    Deserialize<int>(0);
    Deserialize<std::array<int,3>>(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c4fa84d2686997a

I generally find these approaches strongly preferable to partial specialization of a struct with a static method (the other major approach here) as there are many things you can take advantage with functions, and it behaves more intuitively compared to specialization. YMMV.

Comment: I would even name the impl the same name: different arg counts make that pretty safe, and it makes ADL extension less ugly.

Comment: @Yakk A fair point; I think I'll leave the answer as is for maximum clarity for people slightly less familiar with overloading (so they don't mistake it for recursion) but I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

While the functional tag-dispatch is a nice approach, here's a class specialization version for comparison.  Both have their use, and I don't think either is an inherently regrettable decision but maybe one matches your personal style more. 
For any class you write that needs a custom deserialize handler, just write a specialization of the Deserializer class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

using Value = std::string;

// default deserialize function 
template <typename TObject>
struct Deserializer {
    static TObject deserialize(long version, const Value &value) {
        std::cout << "default impl\n";
        return TObject();
    }
};

// free standing function (if you want it) to forward into the classes
template <typename TObject>
TObject deserialize(long version, const Value &value) {
    return Deserializer<TObject>::deserialize(version, value);
}

// Stub example for your Vec class
template<typename TNum, int cnt> class Vec { };

// Stub example for your Vec deserializer specialization
template <typename TNum, int cnt> struct Deserializer<Vec<TNum, cnt>> {
    static auto deserialize(long version, const Value &value) {
        std::cout << "specialization impl: cnt=" << cnt << "\n";
        return Vec<TNum, cnt>();
    }
};

int main() {
    Value value{"abcdefg"};
    long version = 1;

    deserialize<int>(version, value);
    deserialize<Vec<int, 10>>(version, value);
}
```

Comment: This approach does have notable downsides, although in this case where you only return the type in question and don't accept it, it's less apparent. One of them is that it works much more poorly for polymorphic types; specialization does not mix well with inheritance. Functions also give you conversion to const for free; sometimes with specialization you can even get bitten because `T` and `const T` are different types!

Comment: @NirFriedman Those are good points, thanks.  :)  But I fail to see how a tagged dispatch taking Tag<Vec> and Tag<DerivedVec> would work differently, as the Tag class instantiations have no polymorphic relationship.

Comment: Like I said, you won't see it here, because you are returning different types which can't be polymorphic anyhow. But if you were were accepting the type by reference, you would get that conversion for free (as well as const qualifications). The main thing to keep in mind is that duplicating specialization with overloading is trivial, my answer shows that. But overloading gives you access to a lot of useful techniques that are much more work to replicate with specialization.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally in this situation, `Vec` should reflect its own template parameters as members `Vec::value_type` and `Vec::size()` which should be `constexpr`.

If the class fails to provide its own properties in its own interface, the next best thing is to define your own extension interface. In this situation, you can have separate metafunctions (like accessor functions), or a traits class (like a helper view class). I'd prefer the latter:

```
template< typename >
struct vector_traits;

template< typename TNum, int cnt >
struct vector_traits< Vec< TNum, cnt > > {
    typedef TNum value_type;
    constexpr static int size = cnt;
};

template<typename TVec> TVec Deserialize(long version, Value &value) {
    typedef vector_traits< TVec > traits;
    typedef typename traits::value_type TNum;
    constexpr static int cnt = traits::size;
    …
}
```

This solution fits into any existing function, and even makes the signatures cleaner. Also, the function is more flexible because you can adapt it by adding `traits` specializations instead of entire new overloads.

Comment: This approach assumes that Deserialize only takes vector types to deserialize.  What if there's an unrelated Foo class that needs to be deserialized?  Specialize vector_traits so it will compile?

Comment: Clearly the function body can only work with types that are conceptually vectors. Disable the function signature for other types (by SFINAE or Concepts) and provide more overloads.